# Overriding highlighted selection in UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uipickerview

I have a custom `UIPickerView` where I use:

```
-(UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
       viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
     forComponent:(NSInteger)component 
      reusingView:(UIView *)view
```

to populate the picker with `UILabels`.  Is there a way to disable the behavior of highlighting the selected row when touched?

I think this is a property of the underlying `UITableViewCell` inherent in the `UIPickerView` and I can't find a way to change it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to make sure your custom view has the following properties:

1. It needs to be sized to the same dimensions that the UIPickerView expects based on your delegate methods -- `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` and `pickerView:widthForComponent:`. The default height is 44 if you're not specifying a custom height.
2. The background color must be `[UIColor clearColor]`.
3. The view must capture all touches.

The one gotcha when using `UILabel` instances as the custom view is that `UILabel` defaults `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` (`UIView`, on the other hand, defaults this property to `YES`).

Based on these requirements, the example code from [Halle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958443/overriding-highlighted-selection-in-uipickerview/977036#977036) can be rewritten as follows. This example also correctly reuses previously created views, which is needed for fast scrolling performance.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
            viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
          forComponent:(NSInteger)component
           reusingView:(UIView *)view {

  UILabel *pickerRowLabel = (UILabel *)view;
  if (pickerRowLabel == nil) {
    // Rule 1: width and height match what the picker view expects.
    //         Change as needed.
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 44);
    pickerRowLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    // Rule 2: background color is clear. The view is positioned over
    //         the UIPickerView chrome.
    pickerRowLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    // Rule 3: view must capture all touches otherwise the cell will highlight,
    //         because the picker view uses a UITableView in its implementation.
    pickerRowLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  }
  pickerRowLabel.text = [pickerDataArray objectAtIndex:row];  

  return pickerRowLabel;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Setting the `userInteractionEnabled` property of `UILabel` to `YES` fixes the highlighting issue, but it also disables the `UIPickerView` from autoscrolling to select the row that has been touched.

If you want to disable the highlighting behavior, but maintain the `UIPickerView`'s default autoscrolling functionality, call the `setShowSelection` function in the `UITableCell` instances contained in the `UIPickerView`. A way of doing this is to subclass the `UILabel` class similar to the following:

PickerViewLabel.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PickerViewLabel:UILabel 
{
}

@end
```

PickerViewLabel.m -

```
#import "PickerViewLabel.h"

@implementation PickerViewLabel

- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
 if ([[self superview] respondsToSelector:@selector(setShowSelection:)])
 {
  [[self superview] performSelector:@selector(setShowSelection:) withObject:NO];
 }
}

@end
```

Then, where you had previously been returning an instance of `UILabel` in `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`, return an instance of `PickerViewLabel`. As an example, using the code from [Doug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958443/overriding-highlighted-selection-in-uipickerview/1433901#1433901), you would replace all the cases of '`UILabel`' with '`PickerViewLabel`'. Just remember to remove the `pickerRowLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;` line.

Comment: Hi Christine, I implemented the same above code but still blue selection comes at both end of selected row. When I try to debug the code, I found that didMoveToSuperview is not called anywhere. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Hey Shailesh, It's hard to say w/o seeing your code, but I have a few ideas as to why it would not be called. 'didMoveToSuperview' is a function of UIView that gets called automatically anytime that a UIView is added or removed from a view. Is your custom view definitely being added to the screen? If you do a quick test and add an instance of your class as a subview of a UIViewController's view, do you see 'didMoveToSuperview' being called then? If not, I would guess that you have a typo somewhere in the function declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you may want to look at "showsSelectionIndicator" property of UIPickerView

Comment: The showsSelectionIndicator is responsible for displaying the blue bar over the value that will be returned by the picker.  It unfortunately has nothing to do with the underlying UITableViewCell structure.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to remove the selection feedback, but you can cover it up if you make the background of the label white and size it to the same dimensions as the blue selection rectangle:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {

    UILabel *pickerRowLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 316, 40)];
    pickerRowLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    pickerRowLabel.text = [pickerDataArray objectAtIndex:row];  
    [self.view addSubview:pickerRowLabel];

    return pickerRowLabel;

}
```

With a width of 316 the label covers all but a sliver of blue on each side, and at 320 it completely covers the selection feedback but it also starts to cover a bit of the outer wheel gradients, which may or may not bother you.