# HighLight Selection and Autoscroll up/down when using custom view in UIPickecrView

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I have used CustomView.h and CustomView.m from UICatalog sample into my PickerView. But row is not selected/highlighted and scrolled up/down automatically. While the same is happened in standard picker view. How can I select/highlight and scroll up/down automatically with custom view in UIPicker? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958443/overriding-highlighted-selection-in-uipickerview/1785804#1785804). Add the following code to your CustomView.m file:

```
- (void)didMoveToSuperview
{
 if ([[self superview] respondsToSelector:@selector(setShowSelection:)])
 {
  [[self superview] performSelector:@selector(setShowSelection:) withObject:NO];
 }
}
```

And also add `self.userInteractionEnabled = NO` to the `(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame` function.
This will allow you to keep the default autoscroll behavior of the `UIPickerView`.