# Removing UIPickerView Blue Highlight

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

For some time now I've been trying to remove the blue highlight in `UIPickerView` when you're using the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` delegate.

I'm sure many here have been there and wanted to remove that ugly blue highlight in the `UIPickerView`.

The `UIPickerView` has a `UITableView` - rather a `UIPickerTable` inside which has cells where your `UILabels/UIViews/UIImageViews` or whatever lay.
Logically, if it's a tableview, then we can just access the cell and `setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` right?
**Wrong.**

`UIPickerTable` is a private class of the API and does not allow you to set anything in there.

I've managed to get all the subviews in my picker

```
[[myPickerView subviews] objectAtIndex:someIndexValue];
```

So I tried this in `pickerView:didSelectRow:` and `pickerView:viewForRow:`

```
NSIndexPath *path = [[[myPickerView subviews] objectAtIndex:5] indexPathForSelectedRow];
[[[[myPickerView subviews] objectAtIndex:5] cellForRowAtIndexPath:path] setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

And this:

```
[[[myPickerView subviews] objectAtIndex:5] setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

None of them worked 'cause it's private. Giving me this error:

> ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPickerTable setSelectionStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x64479a0'***

I know about setting the `view`'s frame to the size of the `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` and then doing:

```
label.UserInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Before returning it on `pickerView:viewForRow` method.

But it doesn't really remove the highlight, it just **covers** it and removes the UIPickerView's ability to autoscroll when some item is just clicked.

**Does anyone know how can I remove this blue highlight from an `UIPickerView` with an `UILabel/UIView/UIImageView` inside?**

I'm **NOT** talking about the selectionIndicator.
This is the highlight that appears when you click an image inside the pickerView:

[image]

PS: This pickerView has NO `selectionIndicator` and is customized. However, the customization has nothing to do with the issue. This issue is simply for the fact that there's an object that inherits form `UIView` inside the picker's cell and `viewForRow` is being used.

Comment: What highlight are you referring to?

Comment: When you touch an item in your UIPickerView, this item is highlighted in blue. (Note that this will only happen when you're using `pickerView:viewForRow` delegate with objects that inherit from UIView such as UILabels and UIImageViews)

Comment: I have the same issue with UILabels as views. They have the highlight, which is not that important, but also not very great.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't figured a way to remove that. Unfortunately, had to release my app with that. Hopefully someone knows a way or Apple will fix that.

Answer (score 0):

How about [Overriding highlighted selection in UIPickerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958443/overriding-highlighted-selection-in-uipickerview)

Comment: It doesn't really remove the Blue Highlight, it just makes your view the same size of it so it will rather just hide it, which would be great already if it didn't take away a very important feature of the PickerView which is to select an item in a row other then the already selected one just by clicking it. And that is due to ` pickerRowLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;`

Comment: So do u just want to remove the blue highlighted selection above the label.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Just remove the blue highlighted selection on the cell.

Comment: pickerObject.showsSelectionIndicator=NO;
OR you can open the xib, open the Picker View Inspector and deselect the checkmark in Show Selection Indicator

Comment: Nope, that's the Selection Indicatior, not the highlight. I'll just upload a picture so people know what I'm talking about. :)

Comment: Done, check the main post to see it.