# Customize the UIPickerView in IPhone app

Tags: iphone, customization, uipickerview

I would like to know the possibility on increasing the "selection bar" of the UIPickerView
Just to aid the users who are all having the bigger fingers

Please let me know , is that possible

Comment: r you  want to increase the height and width of label in "selection bar"

Comment: No.. i want to increase the "selection bar".. not the text which lies under that bar..

Comment: use this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/958443/overriding-highlighted-selection-in-uipickerview/1433901#1433901

Comment: ya.. i have checked.. by used that link, there is no "selection bar" increasing. it increases row component type only..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I dont think you can actually do anything about the default UI of the picker view. You can try to change the height of the picker view to your desired height by creating it through the code  like this.

```
makePicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 120.0);
```

But if you really want to increase the height of the selection bar itself, i think you might have to make an image and add the image to the picker view which i doubt is an elegant way of achieving what you want. So i would still suggest changing the height o it to make it look a little bigger